# Which law requires a pharmacist to be present in every pharmacy?

Tags: united-states, federalism

Which law requires a pharmacist to be present in every pharmacy in the United States?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies from jurisdiction to jurisdiction. In the United States, the laws are at the state level and can usually be found by googling "pharmacist in charge"and the state name.

Some states' laws are based off the National Association of Boards of Pharmacy's Model Rules for the Practice of Pharmacy, which includes the relevant language in section 3(a)(1):

> No Person shall operate a Pharmacy without a Pharmacist-in-Charge. The Pharmacist-in-Charge of a Pharmacy shall be designated in the application of the Pharmacy for license, and in each renewal thereof. A Pharmacist may not serve as Pharmacist-in-Charge unless he or she is physically present in the Pharmacy a sufficient amount of time to provide supervision and control. A Pharmacist may not serve as Pharmacist-in-Charge for more than one Pharmacy at any one time except upon obtaining written permission from the Board.